# document.getElementById("box").focus() not focusing on element

Tags: javascript, html, focus, dom-events, riot.js

Seeing if anyone can help me figure out why my element isn't focusing.

I'm using RiotJS events and tags. But I don't think this problem has to do with Riot since I tried it with an element on the DOM and pure JS and it still doesn't work.

In the console, when I ask for `document.activeElement` it gives me `<input tabindex="0" id="box" type="text" placeholder="Search">` but it's not focused.

What's weirder is that I made an `onblur` function that focused back on the element onblur and it works! But when I tried tying it to the click [so I can trigger it via `app.search.box.click();`], it doesn't work.

I've googled a LOT and have tried a LOT of the suggestions on how to do this with pure JS.

I'm on OSX Yosemite. Using latest Chrome, Firefox AND Safari. No luck on anything. Please advise.

Here's my `search.tag` code:

```
<search>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="close" onclick={ close }><i class="fa-remove fa"></i></a>

  <div class="elements">

    <input tabindex="0" id="box" type="text" placeholder="Search things" onkeyup={ search } onclick={ focusBox } />

    <span id="loading" class="hide"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-spin"></i></span>

    <a id="searchButton" href="javascript:void(0)" name="search">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </a>

  </div>


  <script>
    this.search = function(event) {
      app.search.trigger('search', event, box.value);
    }

    this.close = function(event) {
      app.search.trigger('close');
    }

    this.focusBox = function(event){
      var element = event.target || event.srcElement;
      window.setTimeout(function() {element.focus()}, 1000);
    }


  </script>

</search>
```

Here's the search.js code that triggers the open:

```
search.open = function(event) {
  search.container.classList.remove('hide');
  search.container.classList.remove('closed');
  search.box.focus();
}
```

Comment: It seems to work fine here, unless i'm misunderstanding your goals: http://jsfiddle.net/60t8we4y/ clicking the input, then clicking out, results in the input regaining focus 1 second later.

Comment: do you want it focused straight away when the page loads ?

Comment: After a certain event EG: A modal is open, or an off-canvas nav opens.